# Why do I get a ValidationError from my Kubernetes configuration file, even though it's valid YAML checked with a linter?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I'm using k8s 1.11.2 to build my service, the YAML file looks like this:

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
  namespace: default
  labels:
  - type: test 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
    - type: test 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
      - type: test 
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.14
        name: filebeat
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    labels:
    - type:test
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.nginx.com
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.125.123
  clusterIP: 10.240.20.1
  ports: 
  - port: 80
    name: tcp
  selector:
  - type: test
```

---

and I get this error:

> error validating data: [ValidationError(Service.metadata.labels):
>   invalid type for
>   io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta.labels: got "array",
>   expected "map", ValidationError(Service.spec.selector): invalid type
>   for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec.selector: got "array", expected
>   "map"];

I am sure the format of my YAML file is right, because I used the website http://www.yamllint.com/ to validate it.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: My question is: Why isn't it showing WHICH LINE NUMBER the error is at? In a large yaml file this error is totally useless, as I don't know where it is. Is it too much to ask for kubectl to tell us where it found the error?

Answer (score 46):

[yamllint.com](http://www.yamllint.com/) is a dubious service because it does not tell us which YAML version it is checking against and which implementation it is using. Avoid it.

More importantly, while your input may be valid YAML, this does not mean that it is a valid input for kubernetes. YAML allows you to create any kind of structure, while kubernetes expects a certain structure from you. This is what the error is telling you:

> got "array", expected "map"

This means that at a place where kubernetes expects a *mapping* you provided an array (*sequence* in proper YAML terms). The error message also gives you the path where this problem occurs:

> ValidationError(Service.metadata.labels):

A quick check on metadata labels in kubernetes reveals [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/), which states that labels need to be mappings, not arrays.

So in your input, the last line here is the culprit:

```
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
  namespace: default
  labels:
  - type: test
```

`-` is a YAML indicator for a sequence item, creating a sequence as value for the key `labels:`. Dropping it will make it a mapping instead:

```
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
  namespace: default
  labels:
    type: test
```

Comment: You advised paying attention to the path given in the error message... and then you yourself ignored it :(

Comment: Thanks, even knowing these things working with yaml is so boring that I need enlightenment every error on helm. Many times, it doesn't even say what file has the problem

Answer (score 6):

In yaml formatting the character "-" implies the start of an array.

You have:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    labels:
    - type:test
```

You want:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    labels:
      type:test
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your second file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    labels:
    - type:test
        #  ^
```

Above the caret (`^`) it is missing a space making `type:test` a single scalar (string) instead of the mapping which is what you get through using

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    labels:
    - type: test
```

and what is that you program expects.

Both are valid YAML so primitive syntax checking doesn't help you.

Answer (score 2):

Rendering of values from values.yaml to config.yaml :

values.yaml :

---

```
sites:
  - dataprovider: abcd
  - dataprovider: xyzx
```

config.yaml :

---

```
     sites:
 {{ toYaml .Values.sites | indent 10 }}
```